# Is there any way to get the page numbers in a PDF of a search pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, terminal, pdf-generation

I have a PDF named `test.pdf` and I need to search for text `My name` in that PDF.

By using this script, I can do the job:

```
pdftotext test.pdf - | grep 'My name'
```

Is there any way to get the page number up to the text "My name" in terminal itself?

Comment: I didn't get what you are really asking for. You have a PDF file and you want to find page number of a specific text? If so, what do you mean of "terminal itself"?

Comment: With `pdftotext` you can select a certain range of pages. Therefore, you only need to grep each page one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want the linear page number (as opposed to the number which appears on the page), then you can do it by counting form-feed characters while you search for your text. `pdftotext` puts a form-feed at the end of every page, so the number of form-feeds prior to your text is one less than the (linear) page number the text is on. (Or thereabouts. Sometimes PDF files are not what they seem.)

Something like the following should work:

```
pdftotext test.pdf - |
awk -vRS=$'\f' -vNAME="My name" \
    'index($0,NAME){printf "%d: %s\n", NR, NAME;}'
```

The following slightly more complicated solution will prove useful if you want to scan for more than one pattern. Unlike the simple solution above, this one will give you one line per pattern match, even if the same pattern matches twice on the same page:

```
pdftotext test.pdf - |
grep -F -o -e $'\f' -e 'My name' |
awk 'BEGIN{page=1} /\f/{++page;next} 1{printf "%d: %s\n", page, $0;}'
```

You can add as many patterns as you like to the `grep` command (by adding another `-e string` argument). The `-F` causes it to match exact strings, but that's not essential; you could use `-E` and a regex. The awk script assumes that all of the matches will either be a form-feed or a string that was matched, which is what you will get with the `-o` option to grep.

If you are looking for phrases, you should be aware that they might have line breaks (or even page breaks) in the middle. There's not a lot you can do about page breaks, but the first (pure awk) solution will handle line breaks if you change the call to `index` to a regular expression search, and write the regular expression with `[[:space::]]+` replacing every single space in the original phrase:

```
pdftotext test.pdf - |
awk -vRS=$'\f' \
    '/My[[:space:]]+Name/{printf "%d: %s\n", NR, "My Name";}'
```

---

In theory, you could extract the visible page number (or "page label" as it is called), but many PDF files do not retain this metadata and you'd need a real PDF parser to extract it.